# Extending primitive systems in free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

It is a version of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4870226/blocks-for-extending-a-primitive-system-in-a-free-group) I asked on Math.StackExchange (no answers yet). Suppose $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,b$ is a primitive system in a non-abelian free group $F$ (a part of a basis of $F$). Let $c \in F'$ be an element of the commutator subgroup of $F.$ Is there any simple condition on $c$ for the set
$$
a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n, bc
$$
NOT to be a primitive system in $F$? An interesting case is the case where $bc$ is a primitive element of $F.$

Granted, for any given $c \in F',$ we can verify by means of the classical algorithm whether the set generates a free factor of $F,$ or we can reduce the problem to invertibility of a suitable matrix over the group ring $\mathbf Z[F].$

Comment: As you said, it is easy to generate plenty of examples.  But I don't really think that there is any particularly nice characterization of such $c$, or a condition that isn't fairly trivial.

Comment: @Andy Putman: Yes, but there is always a chance that somebody considered the problem.

Comment: @user524124: not really, because there’s no well defined question here. Of course, there is lots of literature on the subject of bases of free groups. Can you be more specific about the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @HJRW: I have no specific problem in mind at the moment. But well, one can study, say the asymptotic behavior of the proportion of the elements of the commutator subgroup of length $\le m$ which satisfy the condition, etc. What I started with is the case when $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,b$ is in fact a basis of $F.$ In this case, the elements $c \in F'$ is in question are pretty understandable.  However, if one drops the condition of being a basis, the problem immediately becomes (much) harder.

Answer (score 4):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut} \DeclareMathOperator{\IA}{IA} \newcommand\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$
Let me make a few comments about this.  I'm going to call primitive systems "partial bases" since that's more standard terminology.  I also am going to index things slightly differently than you to make it line up with my preferred notation.

Let $F_n$ be the free group on $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$.  Since $\Aut(F_n)$ acts transitively on bases for $F_n$, it also acts transitively on size-$k$ partial bases.  You are interested in finding $c \in [F_n,F_n]$ such that $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k,x_{k+1} c\}$ is a partial basis.  Ignoring the condition that $c \in [F_n,F_n]$ for the moment, for any $z \in F_n$ you can find some $c \in F_n$ with $x_{k+1} c = z$.  Thus finding all $c \in F_n$ such that $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k,x_{k+1} c\}$ is a partial basis is equivalent to finding all $z \in F_n$ such that $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k,z\}$ is a partial basis.

Aside from some degenerate cases there isn't a nice answer to this question, but you can rephrase it as follows.  Since $\Aut(F_n)$ acts transitively on size-$(k+1)$ partial bases, what you want to do is determine all elements of $F_n$ of the form $f(x_{k+1})$ for $f \in \Aut(F_n)$ satisfying $f(x_i) = x_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$.  In other words, letting $\Aut(F_n,k)$ be the $\Aut(F_n)$ stabilizer of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$, you want to determine the $\Aut(F_n,k)$-orbits of $x_{k+1}$.

In his paper

J. McCool, Some finitely presented subgroups of the automorphism group of a free group, J.
Algebra 35 (1975), 205–213.

McCool proves that $\Aut(F_n,k)$ is finitely presented and gives an algorithm for finding a presentation for it.  I don't know of a paper that actually runs this algorithm and finds such a presentation, but if you can find generators that at least will give a way to systematically enumerate the $f(x_{k+1})$ and will give some hint as to their structure.

Now let's return to your original question: finding $c \in [F_n,F_n]$ such that $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k,x_{k+1} c\}$ is a partial basis.  Note that $z \in F_n$ can be written in the form $z = x_{k+1} c$ with $c \in [F_n,F_n]$ if and only if $z$ maps to the same element of $\Z^n$ as $x_{k+1}$.  Let $\IA_n$ be the subgroup of $\Aut(F_n)$ consisting of elements that act trivially on $\Z^n$.  The letters "IA" stand for "identity on abelianization"; this is often called the Torelli subgroup of $\Aut(F_n)$.  Also define $\IA_n(k)$ to be the $\IA_n$-stabilizer of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$.  It is then not hard to see that what you want is equivalent to determining the orbit of $x_{k+1}$ under $\IA_n(k)$.

A classical theorem of Magnus says that $\IA_n$ is finitely generated and gives a generating set for it.  See my paper

M. Day, A. Putman
[The complex of partial bases for Fn and finite generation of the Torelli subgroup of $\Aut(F_n)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1914),
Geom. Dedicata 164 (2013), 139-153.

for references and additional information.  I do not know if $\IA_n(k)$ is finitely generated, but I expect it is and that this can be proved using the same ideas that go into proving that $\IA_n$ is finitely generated (but starting with $\Aut(F_n,k)$ instead of $\Aut(F_n)$).  Finding a finite generating set for $\IA_n(k)$ would give you a lot of insight into this problem.

Comment: They're two sides of the same coin, but it seemed to me that the question-asker was trying to find $c$ for which $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k,x_{k+1}c\}$ is *not* a partial basis.

Comment: @SamHopkins: That's a good point, but there is more structure to the $c$ where it is a partial basis.  And determining one is equivalent to determining the other.

Comment: I guess you meant to say that Magnus proved that $ \mathrm{IA}_n$ is finitely generated?

Comment: @HJRW: Whoops, you're right!  That's what happens when you type quickly...

Comment: Nice collection of results! Is it known whether the Torelli subgroup is finitely presented?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: It’s known to not be finitely presented for $n=3$ by a theorem of Krstic-McCool, but this is totally open for higher $n$.

Comment: (for $n=2$ it just consists of inner automorphisms, so it isn’t very interesting)